# Calculating Hypergeometric1F1 for large arguments

Tags: special-functions, gsl

[Cross posted on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77461819/7696914)

I am trying to use the `gsl` library for calculating 1F1. I have some C code.

The following works and matches Mathematica's results for small real arguments `z` but not large arguments:

```
/* file 1F1.c */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <gsl/gsl_sf.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_math.h>

double _1F1( double b,
            double c,
            double z)
{
  double Fa = gsl_sf_hyperg_1F1(b, c, z);
  return Fa;
}

int main()
{

  double b = 100000.0;
  double c = 14.0;
  double z = 0.9;
  double result;   
  
  result = _1F1(b, c, z);
  printf("1F1(%.1f, %.1f, %.1f): %e\n", b, c, z, result);

  /* result = 3.2042*10^236 in Mathematica*/

  z = 10*z;

  result = _1F1(b, c, z);
  printf("1F1(%.1f, %.1f, %.1f): %e\n", b, c, z, result);       

  /* result = 9.52444189237289*10^794 in Mathematica*/

  return 0;
}
```

I get:

```bash
$    gcc -std=c17 -Wall -pedantic 1F1.c -lm -lgsl -lcblas; ./a.out
1F1(100000.0, 14.0, 0.9): 3.204195e+236
1F1(100000.0, 14.0, 9.0): -nan
```

So, how do I get around and evaluate for large `z`, as Mathematica seems to be able to do?

I also tried using the Cephes library version and got into the same problem.

I guess I am trying to understand why Mathematica does not have this problem, i.e. what approximation formula for large arguments they are using here. Is there something else I can use here?

Comment: I don't think you can even represent the result as a double, even if the routine internally were to use some higher precision. The largest double is approximately $1.8 \times 10^308$. Mathematica maybe uses some kind of arbitrary precision arithmetic or just quadruple precision.

Comment: I think @Tyberius is on the right track. The 1F1 function grows exponentially. Just because Mathematica gives you *some* number does not mean that you should expect it to be correct or accurate.

Comment: Thanks for this! I converted the cephes code from `double` to `long double` and now I get Inf for `z = 9.0`. I guess that is beter than `nan` and so I also think that @Tyberius is correct, thanks!

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth that is right: there is no reason to believe that Mathematica is correct here. Perhaps one way to check is to go for extended double precision in the C code.

Comment: @user3236841 A better approach is to find an implementation to gives you the log of 1F1. That's a more reasonable function for which you can reason about correctness without having to worry about floating point overflow.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth, Excellent point: does such implementation of the log of 1F1 exist? I did not know of such a function.

Comment: I believe there is a representation of the form $M(a,b,z) = e^z f(a,b,1/z)$ where $f$ is well behaved, maybe even bounded, as $z \rightarrow \infty$, but I don’t recall it. If nothing else it isolates a bit or maybe all of the exponential behavior, and you might be able to take advantage of that.

Comment: http://www.cs.unc.edu/Research/Image/MIDAG/p01/biostat/Digital_1.pdf

Comment: Abramowicz-Stegun is the historically first place I would look. Today that is all collected in a website that is called something like the NIST handbook of special functions or similar.

Comment: Thanks!  There appears to be an implementation of the Kummer function in the `scModels` package in `R` however there is a requirement that `c` above is greater than `b` and there are no references as to what algorithm is used.

Comment: Did you check the implementation in [mpmath](https://mpmath.org/doc/current/functions/hypergeometric.html#mpmath.hyp1f1). It handles arbitrary precision arithmetic.

Comment: I checked your example in mpmath and obtained the same result:

```python
>>> import mpmath
>>> from mpmath import *
>>> hyp1f1(100000.0, 14.0, 9.0)
mpf('9.5244418923728841e+794')
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to use mpmath library in a C (or similar) code call?

Comment: Not that I know.

Comment: Maybe try GNU mpfr.

Comment: Thank you! Did not realize they had 1F1 computations. I will look into it.

Answer (score 2):

> So, how do I get around and evaluate for large z, as Mathematica seems to be able to do?

I think that they use [arbitrary precision arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic) (see [this](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/ControlThePrecisionAndAccuracyOfNumericalResults.html)).

If I check this computation in [Maxima](https://maxima.sourceforge.io/) (I tried it on my phone, though)

```
hypergeometric([100000.0], [14.0], 9.0)
```

I get the following

$$9.524441892372884_B \times 10^{794}$$

If I try it on [mpmath](https://mpmath.org/doc/current/functions/hypergeometric.html#mpmath.hyp1f1)

```py
>>> import mpmath
>>> from mpmath import *
>>> hyp1f1(100000.0, 14.0, 9.0)
```

I get the following

```py
mpf('9.5244418923728841e+794')
```

This is the same result as in SymPy since it uses mpmath internally.

> Is there something else I can use here?

You would need an implementation of special functions and arbitrary precision at the same time. I do not know of C packages for that off the top of my head, though.